# Bootstrap 3 - Push/Pull - 3 Column Layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been struggling with bootstrap's push/pull for a while now and just can't get it to work. I know that I am supposed to think mobile first, but still don't understand it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is what I want:

sm & xs

```
-----------------------------------------------
|                      col1                   |
-----------------------------------------------
|                      col2                   |
-----------------------------------------------
|                      col3                   |
-----------------------------------------------
```

md

```
-----------------------------------------------
|         col 1        |          col 2       |
-----------------------------------------------
|                     col3                    |
-----------------------------------------------
```

lg

```
-----------------------------------------------
|     col1     |     col2     |      col3     |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need push and pull methods, just do this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">1</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">2</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">3</div>
```

Comment: Yep and you don't even need the col-sm-* rules because xs covers it. Fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/sharebert/yrwLmmn7/3/

Comment: OK.. that's what I had done in the first place, so there must be something wrong with my layout.

When the 3rd column shifts down, it expands and covers the first two completely.

I will look more at my code and see what is causing that...

Comment: @Trick Kramer - Add a jsfiddle example with what you have and I might find the problem.